# How to set EF 6.2 MergeOption?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6.2 .Net Framework and I want to set MergeOption of my query to PreserveChanges. How can I do that?
I used code below

```
((ObjectQuery)query).MergeOption = MergeOption.PreserveChanges;
```

but it throws

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TB_CLASSES]'
>   to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

Is this option for .Net core only?
I could not find `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery` in `System.Data` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

MergeOptions are set on the entity type/object, not on the query itself.
That's why casting your query to an object query doesnt work.